# jmeter SampleResult.setSuccessful(false) not working

Tags: python, java, jmeter, traffic

I'm using a loop of beanShell samplers starting threads and, for each thread, a python script is executed, that returns a particular string. I want the thread to fail if the returning string contains a specific error.

Here my code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process p = r.exec("python myscript.py");
p.waitFor();
BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
String line = "";
StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
while ((line = b.readLine()) != null) {
    response.append(line);
    response.append("\n");
}
b.close();

if (response.toString().contains("ERROR-TRAFFIC")){
    SampleResult.setResponseCode("500"); 
    SampleResult.setSuccessful(false);
}
```

Using this code, if condition is correctly executed when the error is present, but in the traffic results I don't see any thread failure. Any hints ??

Answer (score 0):

1. Check [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) for any suspicious entries
2. Check if your `response` variable contains the line you're looking for, you can print it to i.e. the aforementioned `jmeter.log` file with the following line of code:

   ```
   log.info(response.toString());
   ```

   and see what is being returned
3. [Since JMeter 3.1 it's recommended to use JSR223 Sampler and Groovy language for scripting](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) mainly for performance reasons. Moreover Groovy has some "syntax sugar" so your code can be shortened to something like:

   ```
   String response = "python myscript.py".execute().text

   if (response.contains("ERROR-TRAFFIC")){
       SampleResult.setResponseCode("500");
       SampleResult.setSuccessful(false);
   }
   ```

More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)

Comment: Thank you for your response. I already added response log and checked it contains my error. Jmeter.log does not help to understand the problem. So you think code syntax is ok, right? I can't get where the problem is.. any other hint by chance ?

Comment: I know for sure that IF loop is executed correctly because I added some logs to catch where it enters the condition.. only when there is the error, IF is executed.. the problem is around its content maybe

Comment: UPDATE: it works using JSR223, I did no change to the code... Thank you for your support